# 404 on Karma when trying to use web worker

Tags: karma-runner, web-worker

I'm getting the error `WARN [web-server]: 404: /app/workers/total.js` when trying to run a unit test on a web worker.

`Karma.conf.js` includes the following:

```
...
files: [
        ...
        'app/workers/*.js',
        'unit-tests/mocks/**/*.js',
        'unit-tests/src/**/*.js'
    ],
....
```

the test goes as follows:

```
describe('totals', function () {
    var worker;

    beforeEach(function() {
        worker = new Worker('/app/workers/total.js');
    });

    it('should do something', function () {
        ...
    });
});
```

I have tried many urls, but none seem to work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found the solution on https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/1302, the trick is to include `/base` as part of the worker URL, being the solution:

```
describe('totals', function () {
    var worker;

    beforeEach(function() {
        worker = new Worker('/base/app/workers/total.js');
    });

    it('should do something', function () {
        ...
    });
});
```

Note **/base** as part of the worker URL.

Thanks to maksimr